# .NET NodaTime How do I create a custom TimeZone?

Tags: c#, .net, timezone, nodatime

I want to create a custom (non-existing) TimeZone which follows exactly the same rules as Europe/London however the only difference is that the offset should be -5 hours from UTC.

For testing purposes, this is what I was trying. How do I specify daylightsavings? Or is this implementation completely wrong?

```
   public class MyTimeZone : DateTimeZone
    {
        public MyTimeZone()
            : base("MyTimeZone", true, Offset.FromHours(-5), Offset.FromHours(-5))
        {

        }

        protected override bool EqualsImpl(DateTimeZone zone)
        {
            if (zone.Id == "MyTimeZone")
                return true;

            return false;
        }

        public override int GetHashCode()
        {
            return 0001;
        }

        public override NodaTime.TimeZones.ZoneInterval GetZoneInterval(Instant instant)
        {
            return new ZoneInterval("MyTimeZone", new Instant(DateTime.MinValue.Ticks), new Instant(DateTime.MaxValue.Ticks), Offset.FromHours(-5), Offset.FromHours(-5));
        }
    }
```

Comment: I've never used NodaTime before, but I can tell you that your `GetHashCode` function is completely wrong.  It needs to return a value that is relatively unique in order to identify different values.  I would recommend returning the hash code of the zone id.  My guess is that the base class should already be doing something like that.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I'll make sure to correct it.

Comment: I don't think NodaTime has an API to do this easily, but I'm sure Jon will come around to answer this soon enough. :)  Curious, what is the business/application use case for this?  I'm always curious when people say they need custom time zones.  Most actual real-world usage doesn't really need that, as far as I've experienced.

Comment: @BradleyUffner: No, returning a constant value is always a *correct* implementation of `GetHashCode`. It's usually not *optimal*, but it always obeys the contract of `GetHashCode`. Returning the hash of the ID would be better, sure... but to say it's "completely wrong" is... completely wrong.

Comment: @MattJohnson I personally dislike the idea of creating custom timezones. Playing about with time just doesn't seem right. I cannot disclose the business logic but we have custom timezones in our application to handle certain type of processing.

Comment: Currently we have a poor implementation of timezone handling therefore I'm using NodaTime to improve it.

Comment: @Abz - If it's something about trying to treat times past midnight as the same logical business day, typically time zone shifting is a hack and you're better off writing it into the actual business logic.  Just my experience.

Answer (score 3):

This certainly isn't a terribly common scenario, but it's definitely supported. (Unlike creating your own calendar, for example.)

You'd specify daylight saving via `GetZoneInterval` - that method is the key to the class. The important things to get right are:

- Chained constructor call with min/max offset (your max will be UTC-4, not UTC-5)
- `GetZoneInterval`
- Equality/hash code, which you could always make identity equality for the moment.

So for example, you could have:

```
public class LondonOffsetZone : DateTimeZone
{
    private readonly DateTimeZone london;

    // This assumes London has a minimum of +0 and a maximum of +1.
    // To do it better, you'd resolve Europe/London and find *its*
    // min/max, and add -5 hours to each.
    public LondonOffsetZone()
        : base("LondonOffset", false, Offset.FromHours(-5), Offset.FromHours(-4))
    {
        london = DateTimeZoneProviders.Tzdb["Europe/London"];
    }

    public override int GetHashCode() => RuntimeHelpers.GetHashCode(this);

    // Base Equals method will have handled reference equality already.
    protected override bool EqualsImpl(DateTimeZone other) => false;

    public override ZoneInterval GetZoneInterval(Instant instant)
    {
        // Return the same zone interval, but offset by 5 hours.
        var londonInterval = london.GetZoneInterval(instant);
        return new ZoneInterval(
            londonInterval.Name,
            londonInterval.Start,
            londonInterval.End,
            londonInterval.WallOffset + Offset.FromHours(-5),
            londonInterval.Savings);
    }
}
```

That will fail - at least in Noda Time 2.0 - at the start and end of time, where the `Start` and `End` properties won't work, but it should be absolutely fine for any instant you're likely to actually encounter.

Comment: Sure, encapsulation of the existing tzdb zone is probably easiest here.  But I wonder how complex it would be if one really had a full set of custom DST transition dates or other offset changes to implement from scratch?

Comment: @MattJohnson: If you already have a set of transition instants, then it would end up looking very much like https://github.com/nodatime/nodatime/blob/master/src/NodaTime/TimeZones/PrecalculatedDateTimeZone.cs#L78

Comment: Can this be fixed so it'll work at the end of time?  I'd like to use this while dining at the restaurant at the end of the universe.

Comment: @Amy: Ha - I'm afraid Noda Time doesn't go quite that far :) It does do 6 impossible things before breakfast every morning though.

Comment: Thank you very much Jon! and the rest of you. This solved my problem.