# .NET NodaTime - Derive custom class from DateTimeZone error

Tags: c#, oop, .net-core, invalidoperationexception, nodatime

[Based on this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39597086/net-nodatime-how-do-i-create-a-custom-timezone), I have this (so I can have a sense of the object later in calling functions).

But it throws an error, and I could do with some help to understand what is wrong in this code..? I have spent a day reading through multiple comprehensive NodaTime documentations, but loosing time now. Perhaps an oversight of something trivial? Cue: [Under Pressure - Queen](https://youtu.be/a01QQZyl-_I)

Error is caused in `GetZoneInterval()` at `return new ZoneInterval()`:
`System.InvalidOperationException: Zone interval extends to the end of time.`

Stack trace:

```
   at NodaTime.Utility.Preconditions.CheckState(Boolean expression, String message)
   at NodaTime.TimeZones.ZoneInterval.get_End()
   at WebApp.PocTasks.Models.HeardIslandDateTimeZone.GetZoneInterval(Instant instant)
   at NodaTime.DateTimeZone.GetUtcOffset(Instant instant)
   at NodaTime.ZonedDateTime..ctor(Instant instant, DateTimeZone zone, CalendarSystem calendar)
   at NodaTime.ZonedDateTime.WithZone(DateTimeZone targetZone)
   at WebApp.PocTasks.DateTimeExtension.ConvertToZonedDateTime(ZonedDateTime zonedDateTime, DateTimeZone dateTimeZone)
   at WebApp.PocTasks.Controllers.HomeController.GetUserTimezoneRecords(ZonedDateTime sourceStartTime, ZonedDateTime sourceEndTime)
```

```
    public class HeardIslandDateTimeZone : DateTimeZone
    {
        private readonly DateTimeZone _brisbane;

        /// <summary>
        /// The Territory of Heard Island and McDonald Islands is an Australian external territory.
        /// <para>French Southern and Antarctic Time (TFT) is 5 hours ahead of Coordinated Universal Time (UTC). This time zone is in use during standard time in: Indian Ocean.</para>
        /// </summary>
        /// <remarks>
        /// <para>Ref: www.timeanddate.com/worldclock/@1547315</para>
        /// </remarks>
        public HeardIslandDateTimeZone()
            : base(
                  "Australia/HeardIsland",
                  false,
                  Offset.FromHours(5),
                  Offset.FromHours(5))
        {
            this._brisbane = DateTimeZoneProviders.Tzdb["Australia/Brisbane"];
        }

        public override int GetHashCode() => RuntimeHelpers.GetHashCode(this);

        public override ZoneInterval GetZoneInterval(Instant instant)
        {
            // Return the same zone interval, but offset by 5 hours.
            var brisbaneInterval = _brisbane.GetZoneInterval(instant);
            return new ZoneInterval(
                brisbaneInterval.Name,
                brisbaneInterval.Start,
                brisbaneInterval.End,
                brisbaneInterval.WallOffset + Offset.FromHours(-5), // taking-off 5 from +10 that is Brisbane.
                brisbaneInterval.Savings);
        }
        
    }
```

My calling POC function is using `HomeController`'s `Index` action and corresponding view.

`HomeController.cs`

```
        [HttpGet]
        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            var meeting = new ViewModelExample();
            meeting.StartTime = new DateTime(2023, 2, 18, 9, 30, 0);
            meeting.EndTime = new DateTime(2023, 2, 18, 10, 30, 0);

            var sydney = DateTimeZoneProviders.Tzdb["Australia/Sydney"];
            meeting.HostStartTime = meeting.StartTime.ConvertToZonedDateTime(sydney);
            meeting.HostEndTime = meeting.EndTime.ConvertToZonedDateTime(sydney);

            var heard = new HeardIslandDateTimeZone();
            meeting.AttendeeStartTime = meeting.HostStartTime.ConvertToZonedDateTime(heard);
            meeting.AttendeeEndTime = meeting.HostEndTime.ConvertToZonedDateTime(heard);
                       
            return View(meeting);
        }
```

And displaying the data on the View is:

```
<div>
    <p>Database Time: @Model.StartTime.ToCustomString() - @Model.EndTime.ToCustomString()</p>
    <p>Host Time (Sydney): @Model.HostStartTime.ToCustomString() - @Model.HostEndTime.ToCustomString()</p>
    <p>Attendee Time (Heard Island): @Model.AttendeeStartTime.ToCustomString() - @Model.AttendeeEndTime.ToCustomString()</p>
</div>
```

Note: `ConvertToZonedDateTime`, `ToCustomString` are simple extension classes to convert (b/w `DateTime` & `ZoneDateTime`) and render to string in formats like `"dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm.ss"` and `"dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm.ss '('o<g>')'"`.

An identical class works well, such as this:

```
// Return the same zone interval, but offset by 1 hour.
            var sydneyInterval = _sydney.GetZoneInterval(instant);
            return new ZoneInterval(
                sydneyInterval.Name,
                sydneyInterval.Start,
                sydneyInterval.End,
                sydneyInterval.WallOffset + Offset.FromHours(1), // adding +1 hr to +10:00 that is Sydney.
                sydneyInterval.Savings);
```

I am hoping to understand what I am missing, why the later works and to resolve the error?

C#, .NET 7, NodaTime 3.1.9, ASP.NET Core Web App, VS 2022

Comment: Please could you post the full stack trace instead of just the type and message? Ideally a [mcve] that uses this zone as well.

Comment: But if you just need a fixed UTC+5 zone, then it would be simpler to use `DateTimeZone.ForOffset`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah, it looks like it's because you're using the `End` property for an interval which extends to the end of time - so it's throwing the (documented) exception.

You can detect this and avoid calling `End` where it's not appropriate:

```cs
return new ZoneInterval(
    sydneyInterval.Name,
    sydneyInterval.HasStart ? sydneyInterval.Start : default(Instant?),
    sydneyInterval.HasEnd ? sydneyInterval.End : default(Instant?),
    brisbaneInterval.WallOffset + Offset.FromHours(-5),
    sydneyInterval.Savings);
```

However, it would be better just to use `DateTimeZone.ForOffset(Offset.FromHours(5))` if you want a fixed offset. Currently your zone will vary between UTC+5 and UTC+6, because [Australia/Brisbane varies between UTC+10 and UTC+11](https://nodatime.org/tzvalidate/generate?version=2023c&zone=Australia/Brisbane), or at least did until 1992.

Comment: Thanks so much for this! NodaTime docs are amazing, but I just got lost. I added an example identical to what I am working with and also the error stack trace. I resolved the problem for now using the ternary operator as above. Thanks for pointing out the caveat with using Brisbane. I was unable to quickly workout `ZonedDateTime.ForOffset..` but will try it out soon and probably use it as recommended.

Comment: couldn't find a function call for `ZonedDateTime.ForOffset(Offset.FromHours(5))`. That would be a perfect solution. if its not too much to ask, would you be able to edit this answer to include a return statement with this? thanks again..

Comment: @foxfuzz: Doh - that was my fault, it's `DateTimeZone.ForOffset`, not `ZonedDateTime.ForOffset`. (If you want to use values which just have a fixed UTC offset without necessarily knowing the actual time zone, use the `OffsetDateTime` type.)

Comment: thanks a ton! sorry about being a noob.

Comment: @foxfuzz: There's never a need to apologise for that. Hopefully if you have any other Noda Time questions I'll be able to help you with them.